# Calling spring RestFul (Jersey) file upload web service using C# .net client

Tags: c#, .net, spring, rest, upload

Can anyone please suggest a step by step tutorial for Client RESTful in c# .net, for calling spring mvc restful web service (jersey) file upload.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the Spring.NET REST Client :

http://www.springframework.net/rest/